# Dynamic Runtime 3D Points in WPF

Tags: wpf, 3d, point-clouds

I am trying to create a dynamic view of 3D points using WPF, I am able to draw the first set of points but then it crashes bcuz the Mesh3DGeometry is frozen .. is there anyway to unfreeze the Mesh3DGeomerty and Clear the Grid so the next sets can be drawn ?

```
    var rand = new Random();
while (true)
{
    points.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        points.Add(new Point3D(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble()));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < points.Count; i++)
    {
        AddCubeToMesh(pointCloudMesh, points[i], 0.01);
    }
    pointCloudMesh.Freeze();
}
```

Also XAML is here

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="0 20 0 -20" Background="LightGray" Name="MyCanvas" >
                <Viewport3D>
                    <Viewport3D.Camera>
                        <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain" Position="0 0 5" LookDirection="0 0 -5"/>
                    </Viewport3D.Camera>

                    <ModelVisual3D>
                        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                            <Model3DGroup>
                                <Model3DGroup.Children>
                                    <AmbientLight Color="#AAAAAA" />
                                </Model3DGroup.Children>
                            </Model3DGroup>
                        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    </ModelVisual3D>

                    <ModelVisual3D>
                        <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                            <GeometryModel3D>
                                <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                    <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="pointCloudMesh" />
                                </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                                <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                                    <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Red"/>
                                </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            </GeometryModel3D>
                        </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    </ModelVisual3D>
                </Viewport3D>
            </Grid>
```

Code for AddCubeToMesh

```
private void AddCubeToMesh(MeshGeometry3D mesh, Point3D center, double size)
    {
        if (mesh != null)
        {
            int offset = mesh.Positions.Count;

            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(center.X - size, center.Y + size, center.Z - size));
            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(center.X + size, center.Y + size, center.Z - size));
            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(center.X + size, center.Y + size, center.Z + size));
            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(center.X - size, center.Y + size, center.Z + size));
            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(center.X - size, center.Y - size, center.Z - size));
            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(center.X + size, center.Y - size, center.Z - size));
            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(center.X + size, center.Y - size, center.Z + size));
            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(center.X - size, center.Y - size, center.Z + size));

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 3);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 2);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 6);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 3);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 6);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 7);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 2);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 1);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 5);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 2);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 5);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 6);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 1);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 0);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 4);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 1);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 4);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 5);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 0);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 3);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 7);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 0);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 7);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 4);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 7);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 6);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 5);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 7);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 5);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 4);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 2);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 3);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 0);

            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 2);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 0);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(offset + 1);
        }
    }
```

I solution that kinda worked for me is to add all of this into a separated UserControl and call it every time a new data arrive

Comment: I would add the AddCubeToMesh method implementation to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution I came up with is to separate the Point Cloud view to another User Control and every time I wanna display a new set of data i destroy the old User Control and rebuild it .. it's an aggressive approach but worked fine

XAML for the new User Control

```
<UserControl x:Class="LPDTool.View3D"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LPDTool"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="500"
         KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
<GroupBox x:Name="GBox" Margin="0 20 0 -20" Foreground="#AAAAAA" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Medium" Background="#DDDBDA" BorderBrush="#7B7704" BorderThickness="2" FontFamily="Abadi MT">
    <Viewport3D>
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain"/>
        </Viewport3D.Camera>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <Model3DGroup>
                    <Model3DGroup.Children>
                        <AmbientLight Color="#AAAAAA" />
                    </Model3DGroup.Children>
                </Model3DGroup>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
        <ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <GeometryModel3D>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="pointCloudMesh" />
                    </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                    <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                        <DiffuseMaterial Brush="Red"/>
                    </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                </GeometryModel3D>
            </ModelVisual3D.Content>
        </ModelVisual3D>
    </Viewport3D>
</GroupBox>
```

Initialization Constructor

```
public View3D()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        PositionCamera();

        for (int i = 0; i < LPDTest.points.Count; i++)
        {
            AddCubeToMesh(pointCloudMesh, points[i], 0.02);
        }
    }
```

XAML for the inclusion part

```
<Grid x:Name="My3dview">

</Grid>
```

Here is the generating code part (with dumpy data)

```
var rand = new Random();
while (true)
{
    My3dview.Children.Clear();
    points.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        points.Add(new Point3D(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble()));
    }
    My3dview.Children.Add(new View3D());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: An endless loop that generates UI parts without giving time to the UI Thread is will not work. Generate the data on a seperate thread and pass the data to the UI thread to create the model and display it.

Then, unfreezing a freezable is not possible:

> "Unfreezing" a Freezable Once frozen, a Freezable can never be
> modified or unfrozen; however, you can create an unfrozen clone using
> the Clone or CloneCurrentValue method.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/freezable-objects-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

So if you think it is really needed to Freeze/Unfreeze you can do it by making a clone. I don't think it is needed here.

Comment: So the endless loop is just for demo not the actual project. because data is driven from Hardware sensor .. however i solved this by separating the 3D view into another user control and then i can delete all children's and build them again with the new data

Comment: I think it is much faster to add a 100 cubes at the origin and update their translations on every tick.